# Rewrite (mask) dynamic css file name

Tags: css, url-rewriting

I need to modify a dynamic styles file name so people inspecting won't see the real name. Need to change where it says "themename" to another word.

The file path looks like this.

https://my-site/wp-content/uploads/themename-dynamic-styles.css?ver=1560432373

I'm very lost with this, I couldn't understand examples I've found. Thanks

Comment: simply change the filename in the server

Comment: 2 reasons why is not that simple. 1) Using a wordpress theme, which get updates. 2) fIle is called in various instances.